# Prevent SwiftUI from resetting state of a navigation stack

Tags: swiftui

For some unknown reason. Upon reaching the **4th child of the stack**, the Binding attached that displays the 3rd child **gets reset**. The issue here, is **you cannot go back anymore.**

This problem carries over on the 5th child - thus resetting the 4th.

I even tried to inject an environment object from the root hoping to mitigate the issue but it is still the same.

Please try to replicate using the code below.

```
class SceneDelegate: UIResponder, UIWindowSceneDelegate {

  var window: UIWindow?

  var globalEnvironment = GlobalEnviroment()

  func scene(_ scene: UIScene, willConnectTo session: UISceneSession, options connectionOptions: UIScene.ConnectionOptions) {
    let contentView = ContentView().environmentObject(globalEnvironment)

    if let windowScene = scene as? UIWindowScene {
        let window = UIWindow(windowScene: windowScene)
        window.rootViewController = UIHostingController(rootView: contentView)
        self.window = window
        window.makeKeyAndVisible()
    }
  }

  // other callbacks
}
```

Then for the views, I added logging so its easy to see the issue

```
import SwiftUI

class GlobalEnviroment: ObservableObject {
  @Published var isPage2Active = false {
    didSet {
      print(" [2] something set this to \(isPage2Active)")
    }
  }
  @Published var isPage3Active = false {
    didSet {
      print(" [3] something set this to \(isPage3Active)")
    }
  }
  @Published var isPage4Active = false {
    didSet {
      print(" [4] something set this to \(isPage4Active)")
    }
  }
  @Published var isPage5Active = false {
    didSet {
      print(" [5] something set this to \(isPage5Active)")
    }
  }
}

struct ContentView: View {
  @State private var isDetailActive = false
  @EnvironmentObject var env: GlobalEnviroment

  var body: some View {
    print(" [root] redrawing...")
    return NavigationView {
      VStack {
        NavigationLink(destination: Page2(isActive: $env.isPage2Active)
                        .environmentObject(env),
                       isActive: $env.isPage2Active) {
          EmptyView()
        }
        Button(action: {
          env.isPage2Active = true
        }, label: {
          Text("Next")
        })
      }
    }
    .onReceive([env.isPage2Active].publisher.first(), perform: { response in
      print(" 2: \(response)")
    })
    .onReceive([env.isPage3Active].publisher.first(), perform: { response in
      print(" 3: \(response)")
    })
    .onReceive([env.isPage4Active].publisher.first(), perform: { response in
      print(" 4: \(response)")
    })
    .onReceive([env.isPage5Active].publisher.first(), perform: { response in
      print(" 5: \(response)")
    })
    .onAppear {
      print(" ============================================  >>>> ")
      print(" [root] appeared")
    }
    .onDisappear {
      print(" [root] disappear")
      print(" <<<<  ============================================ ")
    }
  }
}

struct Page2: View {
  @Binding var isActive: Bool
  @State private var isDetailActive = false
  @EnvironmentObject var env: GlobalEnviroment

  var body: some View {
    print(" [2] redrawing...")
    return VStack {
      Text("Page 2")
          .padding()
      NavigationLink(destination: Page3(isActive: $env.isPage3Active)
                      .environmentObject(env),
                     isActive: $env.isPage3Active) {
        EmptyView()
      }.isDetailLink(true)
      Button(action: {
        env.isPage2Active = false
      }, label: {
        Text("Back")
      })
        .padding()
      Button(action: {
        env.isPage3Active = true
      }, label: {
        Text("Next")
      })
    }
    .navigationBarBackButtonHidden(true)
    .onAppear {
      print(" ============================================  >>>> ")
      print(" [2] appeared")
    }
    .onDisappear {
      print(" [2] disappear")
      print(" <<<<  ============================================ ")
    }
  }
}

struct Page3: View {
  @Binding var isActive: Bool
  @EnvironmentObject var env: GlobalEnviroment

  var body: some View {
    print(" [3] redrawing...")
    return VStack {
      Text("Page 3")
          .padding()
      NavigationLink(destination: Page4(isActive: $env.isPage4Active)
                      .environmentObject(env),
                     isActive: $env.isPage4Active) {
        EmptyView()
      }.isDetailLink(true)
      Button(action: {
        print("ikaw??")
        env.isPage3Active = false
      }, label: {
        Text("Back")
      })
        .padding()
      Button(action: {
        env.isPage4Active = true
      }, label: {
        Text("Next")
      })
    }
    .navigationBarBackButtonHidden(true)
    .onAppear {
      print(" ============================================  >>>> ")
      print(" [3] appeared")
    }
    .onDisappear {
      print(" [3] disappear")
      print(" <<<<  ============================================ ")
    }
  }
}

struct Page4: View {
  @Binding var isActive: Bool
  @State private var isDetailActive = false
  @EnvironmentObject var env: GlobalEnviroment

  var body: some View {
    print(" [4] redrawing...")
    return VStack {
      Text("Page 4")
          .padding()
      NavigationLink(destination: Page5(isActive: $env.isPage5Active)
                      .environmentObject(env),
                     isActive: $env.isPage5Active) {
        EmptyView()
      }.isDetailLink(true)
      Button(action: {
        env.isPage4Active = false
      }, label: {
        Text("Back")
      })
        .padding()
      Button(action: {
        env.isPage5Active = true
      }, label: {
        Text("Next")
      })
    }
    .navigationBarBackButtonHidden(true)
    .onAppear {
      print(" ============================================  >>>> ")
      print(" [4] appeared")
    }
    .onDisappear {
      print(" [4] disappear")
      print(" <<<<  ============================================ ")
    }
  }
}

struct Page5: View {
  @Binding var isActive: Bool
  @EnvironmentObject var env: GlobalEnviroment

  var body: some View {
    print(" [5] redrawing...")
    return VStack {
      Spacer()
      Button(action: {
        env.isPage5Active = false
      }, label: {
        Text("Back")
      })
        .padding()
      Text("Page 5")
          .padding()
      Spacer()
    }
    .navigationBarBackButtonHidden(true)
    .onAppear {
      print(" ============================================  >>>> ")
      print(" [5] appeared")
    }
    .onDisappear {
      print(" [5] disappear")
      print(" <<<<  ============================================ ")
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`@Binding` seems to be unreliable in deeply nested views, especially in the 5-level hierarchy.

It looks like the `isActive` parameter is also unreliable in multiple nested views.

A possible workaround is to use `@Environment(\.presentationMode)` - this way even if the `Binding` is reset, you still can go to the previous view:

```
struct Page4: View {
  @Environment(\.presentationMode) private var presentationMode // add this
  @EnvironmentObject var env: GlobalEnviroment

  var body: some View {
    print(" [4] redrawing...")
    return VStack {
      Text("Page 4")
          .padding()
      NavigationLink(destination: Page5()
                      .environmentObject(env),
                     isActive: $env.isPage5Active) {
        EmptyView()
      }.isDetailLink(true)
      Button(action: {
        env.isPage4Active = false
        presentationMode.wrappedValue.dismiss() // dismiss to go to the previous view
      }, label: {
        Text("Back")
      })
        .padding()
      Button(action: {
        env.isPage5Active = true
      }, label: {
        Text("Next")
      })
    }
    .navigationBarBackButtonHidden(true)
    .onAppear {
      print(" ============================================  >>>> ")
      print(" [4] appeared")
    }
    .onDisappear {
      print(" [4] disappear")
      print(" <<<<  ============================================ ")
    }
  }
}
```

(Added for one view only but obviously it should be in the *dismiss* action for every view).